# Spring MVC - session and multi-thread

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

Reading [Spring MVC - Session](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) I came across this quote under sessions:

> Session access may not be thread-safe, in particular in a Servlet
>   environment. Consider setting the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter's
>   "synchronizeOnSession" flag to "true" if multiple requests are allowed
>   to access a session concurrently.

1.where can I find an example on how to set `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` to cover `multi-thread`?

2.How does `synchronizeOnSession` works exacly?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't want to use that. Do you really have an issue or do you think you have an issue. synchronizing on the session will slow down your application.

Comment: OK, I don't have a issue so far, but just in case, thank's.